Why is multi processing taking longer than single processor on Windows and Mac?
From what i know if u divide a large task into multiple processes the time taken to complete the task reduces but this is not happening in my code.
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import random

def calculate_squares(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        square = num * num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(100000000)]
    quarter = len(numbers) // 4
    first_part = numbers[:quarter]
    second_part = numbers[quarter:2*quarter]
    third_part = numbers[2*quarter:3*quarter]
    fourth_part = numbers[3*quarter:]

    start_time = time.time()

    # Creating four processes
    p1 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(first_part,))
    p2 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(second_part,))
    p3 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(third_part,))
    p4 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(fourth_part,))

    # Start all processes
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    # Wait for all processes to complete
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time with four processes: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

    # Single process execution for comparison
    start_time = time.time()
    calculate_squares(numbers)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time for single process: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")


this is the code and
output for i5 13gen (windows):
Execution time with four processes: 4975.9681224823 ms
Execution time for single process: 3258.450984954834 ms

output for i3 8gen (linux):
Execution time with four processes: 1378.4070014953613 ms
Execution time for single process: 2259.6046924591064 ms

output for mac m1:
Execution time with four processes: 3175.5270957946777 ms
Execution time for single process: 2120.435953140259 ms


(I think this should have been answered somewhere, but I can't find a question similar enough to close as duplicate, so here goes.)
@KlausD. has it right: the overhead of starting new processes is higher on Windows and by default on MacOS as well, because the entire interpreter state (including all variables) needs to be serialized and sent to other processes. As you can see, on Linux the multiprocessing approach is faster. You can read more about this in the Python documentation: Contexts and start methods.
I'm exclusively using Linux, so to replicate the issue, I've added a call to multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn'). Then let's separately measure the time it takes to start the processes:
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method
import time
import random

def calculate_squares(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        square = num * num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(100000000)]
    quarter = len(numbers) // 4
    first_part = numbers[:quarter]
    second_part = numbers[quarter:2*quarter]
    third_part = numbers[2*quarter:3*quarter]
    fourth_part = numbers[3*quarter:]

    # Creating four processes
    set_start_method('spawn')
    start_time = time.time()
    p1 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(first_part,))
    p2 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(second_part,))
    p3 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(third_part,))
    p4 = Process(target=calculate_squares, args=(fourth_part,))
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Creation time for four processes: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

    # Start all processes
    start_time = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Startup time for four processes: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

    # Wait for all processes to complete
    start_time = time.time()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time with four processes: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

    # Single process execution for comparison
    start_time = time.time()
    calculate_squares(numbers)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time for single process: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

The output on my i7-13700K:
Creation time for four processes: 0.040531158447265625 ms
Startup time for four processes: 1386.2104415893555 ms
Execution time with four processes: 424.9296188354492 ms
Execution time for single process: 1357.4330806732178 ms

So it's clear that most of the time is spent transferring the data to the new processes, not in the actual processing.
And with the more efficient 'fork' method used on Linux by default:
Creation time for four processes: 0.0457763671875 ms
Startup time for four processes: 271.9295024871826 ms
Execution time with four processes: 363.21234703063965 ms
Execution time for single process: 1363.1033897399902 ms


Notwithstanding the comments regarding Process construction overheads, a significant issue here is the size of the objects being passed (serialised) to the sub-processes. That serialisation is notoriously slow in Python.
Here's a rewrite of the test that demonstrates the impact of serialisation:
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

PROCS = 4

def calculate_squares(numbers):
    _ = [x * x for x in numbers]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 50_000_000
    numbers = list(range(N))
 
    start_time = time.time()

    pool = Pool(PROCS)
    try:
        for i in range(PROCS):
            s = i * (N // PROCS)
            e = s + (N // PROCS)
            chunk = numbers[s:e]
            pool.apply_async(calculate_squares, args=(chunk,))
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time with {PROCS} processes: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

    start_time = time.time()
    calculate_squares(numbers)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time for single process: {(end_time - start_time) * 10**3} ms")

Output:
Execution time with 4 processes: 2268.983840942383 ms
Execution time for single process: 1726.7539501190186 ms

Now modify the calculate_squares() function like this:
def calculate_squares(numbers):
    return [x * x for x in numbers]

In other words, we're getting the subprocess to return a value which it will do by serialisation.
The output then becomes:
Execution time with 4 processes: 4975.505113601685 ms
Execution time for single process: 1923.995018005371 ms

Thus we can clearly see how by introducing additional serialisation, the performance drops off significantly.
Platform:
macOS 15.1
Python 3.13.0
Apple Silicon M2

